# How to refresh iAd and specify keyword manually?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ads

I successfully integrated iAd into my iPhone app. However, I can't find a way to refresh the ad manually. I couldn't find a way to specify keywords for the ad either. How does iAd work after all? Does it just show some ads randomly?

Comment: I'm guessing that they won't allow manual reloading of ads, given how that could be used to abuse the CPM system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iAd is totally controlled by Apple based on keywords, the app type and exclusions that you set when you release or modify the app on Itunes Connect. The ads are served only when you release it via ITunes Connect.

Comment: yes, I understand no ad will be served until the app is released. Also, if I understand right, there is no way to refresh the ads manually. If so, can I set some targeting keywords somewhere?

Comment: You can't control the ads. Apple decides based on your type of app and the keywords for your app. You can exclude certain companies from advertising on your app like a competing app and you can set the age range <17 or 17+. That's it...

Comment: I see, that is helpful. But where can I exclude certain companies/apps/age range? Also, the keyword you mentioned is just the keyword I typed in when I submitted my apps in itunes connect?

Comment: When you submit or amend an app on ITunes Connect. Itunes Connect->Manage Your apps->Your App->Update Your Application. The screen after "have you changed your app encryption" etc has all the IAd sign up with the items i mentioned.

It also doesn't go live until 1 of July anyway so you can't check it out properly until then.